# Image compression in bitmap and uploading to server in android Q

Tags: android, uri, android-contentresolver, android-10.0, imageurl

i am trying to upload an image to one of the server but the server side has certain resolution limitations.Hence we are compressing the image file using  bitmap before the upload.

Below is the code for bitmap compression and image insertion in android q framework.

```
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, filename);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");

        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        uri =getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);
        stream=getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
```

we can get a uri from the above code.

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
    Log.d(TAG, "getRealPathFromURI: idx "+idx+"  cursor.getString(idx)"+cursor.getString(idx));

    return cursor.getString(idx);
}
```

But since above method is deprecated,i am unable to get the real path of the uri for android Q.
Can anyone help me with the same.
i already referred File Descriptor,but didnt understood anything.
If possible any example of the same with the above scenario in the mind,would do.
or else if there's any other solution,please suggest the same.
If you are stating solution,please state it for android Q only.

Thank you.

Comment: You do not need 'a real path from uri' to upload an image in a file. You can use the uri directly. But you even dont need an uri or use the mediastore. Now you are compressing the bitmap to an outputstream. That outputstream is for the obtained uri. But better compress your bitmap to the outputstream of the upload function directly.

Comment: Forget about uploading,i needed image path from uri.Currently what i have is in the format of something like /external/images/media/74275.i need it in the format of something like file:///storage/sdcard0/Pictures/X.jpg.is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Please tell first why you want a file uri. You got a content uri. You used data.getPath(). But use data.toString() to see that indeed it is a content:// uri scheme.

Comment: `we can get a uri from the above code.` No. Above code contains already an uri. Use that uri.

Comment: `Forget about uploading,i needed image path from uri.` Ha ha. Tell why you need a file uri for that upload. As said before: you normally dont need that unless you use some specific library to do the upload.

Comment: You didn't understood the question.Did you saw the method getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri).Previosuly i used to get the path of image file using that method.But since that method is not supported for android Q,i need an alternative for the same method?i am having uri with me.not an issue.

Comment: You dont need an alternative as you can directly use the uri instead of 'a path' from it. Your problem is very well understood as every week the last two years the same 'path love' has been reported here. And you still did not tell why you need a file path.

Comment: i need the file path for making an object of file to pass it as parameter to multipart. Anyways ,how can i compress an image and pass it out to make as a request body for Multipart.Prior to Android Q,we were having method : bitmap.insertimage where we can pass the bitmap as parameter to the method.But in Android Q,we are having method getContentresolver().insert where we don't have any option of passing bitmap as parameter.So what's the solution for that?

Comment: Ok. But now i wanna know why you cannot pass that uri to the request body. You could elaborate on that.

Comment: Even if you could obtain the file path it would be useless as on Android Q your app would not have access to that path.

Comment: As your code is now your bitmap will be saved in the Pictures directory i think. So it is in getExternalPublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES). So you know the path... Just try. You can check withe the File class if the file exists and it will say yes. But if you try to read the file you will have no access.

Answer (score 0):

If you really only can upload using the File class and not using an input stream (hard to believe but ala) then on Android Q do not save to the media store but compress your bitmap to a file in getExternalFilesDir() or getFilesDir().

No permissions needed and you have a file path.

Comment: i changed the whole flow of my program and now am not  using getContentresolver().insert to save img to media store.instead i compressed my bitmap to a file in filesdir and send it as parameter to multipart request body.Now it's working.Thanks a lot for your time and clarifications.